# Python Tkinter: destroy() my Toplevel() window

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm trying to create a log in window. When you click Log in, I want to to go do stuff and after that close out and go to the main GUI.

I found a bunch of stuff online that I can't make heads or tails of. I do not want to cut and paste other people's code which I do not fully understand.

So I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here. To start I created a destroyWindow() method which I call from the button as just a starting point. 
There is a scope issue where loginWindow does not exist within its own class. I thought the class application would get around the scope issue. I tried using 'self.' but to no avail. I tried random things I saw in other people's code. Please can someone pinpoint what I'm missing here? I get

> > > NameError: global name 'loginWindow' is not defined

```
#!/Usr/bin/Python
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog,tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import sys, time, datetime
import pathlib
from pathlib import * #makes it really easy to travers folders if needed.

mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.wm_title("my prog")
mainWindow.wm_iconbitmap('fb_logo_sm.ico')
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

class loginWindowClass():
    def __init__(self):
        loginWindow = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        loginWindow.configure(bg='#22BEF2')    
        loginWindowFrame = Frame(loginWindow,bg='#22BEF2')
        loginWindowFrame.grid(padx=90,pady=50)
        loginWindow.wm_title("log in")
        loginWindow.wm_iconbitmap('my.ico')
        usernameLable = Tkinter.Label(loginWindowFrame,text="User Name",fg='#FFFFFF',bg='#22BEF2')
        usernameLable.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=(0,5),sticky=W+S)
        usernameField = Entry(loginWindowFrame)
        usernameField.config(width=24)
        usernameField.grid(row=2,column=2)
        passwordLable =Tkinter.Label(loginWindowFrame,text="Password",fg='#FFFFFF',bg='#22BEF2')
        passwordLable.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+S)
        passwordField = Entry(loginWindowFrame)
        passwordField.config(width=24)
        passwordField.grid(row=4,column=2)
        loginButton = Button(loginWindowFrame, text='Log In', height=1, width=20, wraplength=100,        fg='white',bg='#bbbbbb',command=self.destroyWindow).grid(row=5,column=2,pady=(10,0))
    def destroyWindow(self):
        loginWindow.destroy()

logwin = loginWindowClass()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. 'self.' is the answer indeed.

I did not apply it everywhere. Here is the solution

```
#!/Usr/bin/Python
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog,tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import sys, time, datetime
import pathlib
from pathlib import * #makes it really easy to travers folders if needed.

mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.wm_title("my prog")
mainWindow.wm_iconbitmap('fb_logo_sm.ico')
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

class loginWindowClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loginWindow = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.loginWindow.configure(bg='#22BEF2')    
        loginWindowFrame = Frame(self.loginWindow,bg='#22BEF2')
        loginWindowFrame.grid(padx=90,pady=50)
        self.loginWindow.wm_title("log in")
        self.loginWindow.wm_iconbitmap('my.ico')
        usernameLable = Tkinter.Label(loginWindowFrame,text="User Name",fg='#FFFFFF',bg='#22BEF2')
        usernameLable.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=(0,5),sticky=W+S)
        usernameField = Entry(loginWindowFrame)
        usernameField.config(width=24)
        usernameField.grid(row=2,column=2)
        passwordLable =Tkinter.Label(loginWindowFrame,text="Password",fg='#FFFFFF',bg='#22BEF2')
        passwordLable.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+S)
        passwordField = Entry(loginWindowFrame)
        passwordField.config(width=24)
        passwordField.grid(row=4,column=2)
        loginButton = Button(loginWindowFrame, text='Log In', height=1, width=20, wraplength=100,        fg='white',bg='#bbbbbb',command=self.destroyWindow).grid(row=5,column=2,pady=(10,0))
    def destroyWindow(self):
        self.loginWindow.destroy()

logwin = loginWindowClass()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```